# Is there a fast algorithm for the following?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have two sorted arrays A and B, each of length n.

I also have a set of pairs of indices S, where the indices are between 1 to n. (So for example, if n=3, then S can be (1,2), (2,3) and (1,1)).

I would like a very fast algorithm (preferably O(log n)) such that it finds the pair (i,j) from S that maximizes A[i] + B[j].

Any preprocessing on S can be done (hashing certain values, etc.).

Any O(n log n) preprocessing can be done on A and B (since it takes time to sort them anyway), but once the preprocessing is done, subsequent queries with various preprocessed S's should be fast.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in less than O(n).

If `S={(i,n-i+1)|1≤i≤n}` you have no other solution than testing for each element of S because for `i≠j`, both `A[i]+B[n-i+1] < A[j]+B[n-j+1]` and `A[i]+B[n-i+1] ≥ A[j]+B[n-j+1]` are possible.